# Doc not found/missing after being inserted in couchdb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I'm trying to create a simple db called '_users' and insert a new user into it using Couch-DB.

I'm using Node in the shell to run the following code:

UserProfile.js

```
var nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984')        
module.exports = {
    addUser: function(id, name, password){                
        var usersDB = nano.use('_users')
        var options = {
            "_id": "org.couchdb.user:"+id,
            "name": id,
            "roles": [],            
            "type": "user",
            "password": password
        }
        usersDB.insert(options, function(err, body, header) { 
            console.log('insert is being called')
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
                return;
            }            
            console.log(body);
        });

    }
};
```

node repl

```
> var nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984')
undefined
> var usersdb = nano.db.destroy('_users')
undefined
> var usersdb = nano.db.create('_users')
undefined
> var profile = require('./UserProfile.js')
undefined
> profile.addUser('cheese', 'flubber', 'goat')
undefined
> insert is being called
> OS process timed out.
```

After running this, I expect to see an entry at `/_users/cheese`, but no entry exists.  Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: 1. The expected entry should be /_users/org.couchdb.user:cheese

2. What is the response from the usersDB.insert callback?

Comment: @AlexisCôté  When I go to `/_users/org.couchdb.user:cheese`  I see `{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}`.  There is no response from the callback; as you can see in my shell above, it simply returns undefined.

Comment: The `nano.db.destroy` and `nano.db.create` functions use callbacks - did the API calls resolve before moving to the next call?

Answer (score 1):

when you create a user, the _id must be like this: `org.couchdb.user:name`.

In your case, you create a user cheese with a different name.

Also, you might want to check your error callback. An error message should be returned from Couch.

## Also

When you delete and create the database, you have to use the callback.

When you create _users, you directly create a user even if the _users database has not been confirmed to be created.

Comment: I updated my question to show that I now have the `org:couchdb.user:name` and `name` with the same values (`id`).  Also, I can't check the error callback because the callback is failing to call.  I just get `undefined` returned.